# show that function is discontinous on $C:=\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 \mid x^2+y^2=1\}$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

My question: Is the following solution to the exercise correct or am I missing something? Thanks in advance.

Let $f: C \rightarrow [0,2\pi[$ be defined as $f(x,y)=\arccos(x) \ \ $ for  $y\geq 0$ and $f(x,y)=2\pi - \arccos(x)$ for $y<0$.

I have to show that $f$ is not continous. I  noticed that we could argue with limits showing that for a given $y_n \rightarrow 0$ the limit outsde the function is different then the limit inside, for $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Expicitly, we have the counterexample: $\lim_{ n \rightarrow \infty} f(1-\frac{1}{n},-\sqrt{1-(1-\frac{1}{n})^2})= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (2\pi- \arccos(1-\frac{1}{n}))=2\pi-0=2\pi$

but the inner limit is: $f(\lim_{ n \rightarrow \infty}(1-\frac{1}{n},-\sqrt{1-(1-\frac{1}{n})^2}))=f(\lim_{ n \rightarrow \infty}(1-\frac{1}{n}),\lim_{ n \rightarrow \infty}-\sqrt{1-(1-\frac{1}{n})^2})=f(1,0)=\arccos(1)=0$

since the inner and outer limits are not the same the function is not continous at $y=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your answer is completely right.
Let $n,d \in \mathbb{N}$
$ f : \Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$
Indeed we have that a function $f$ is continuous if for any sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of points in the domain $\Omega$ which converges to $c \in \Omega$, the corresponding sequence $(f(x_n))_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to $f(c)$ $($and $f(c)$ exists$)$.
In mathematical notation:
$f$ continuous iff: $$ \forall (x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset  \Omega : \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n = c \in \Omega \Rightarrow \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(x_n) = f(c) $$

In our case we define $d=2,n=1$ and $\Omega = C$
$C  \ni x_i = (1- \frac{1}{i},-\sqrt{1-(1-\frac{1}{i})^2})$ then $x_i \overset{i\rightarrow \infty}{\rightarrow} c = (1,0^{-}) \in C$ and as you calculated $f(c) = f(1,0) = \arccos(1) =0$

But as you calculated the sequence $f(x_i) \overset{i\rightarrow \infty}{\rightarrow} 2\pi$
Therefore $f$ isn't continuous at $c = (1,0)$ as you wanted.

Comment: thank you for the comfirmation. the official answer to this homework used $\epsilon-\delta$ wich seemed a bit less straightforword to me (hence my doubt that I might miss something). Ps: I will accept the answer soon.